# Hiding different columns on Google sheet using script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanted to hide multiple columns for example column 1,3,5,... is there any method, I can do this using script in Google sheet?

Comment: I'm sure script can do this. Does the `Excel` tag has any relevance?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide only odd rows, can use this:

```
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var first_column =1;
 var last_column = 10;
 for( var i = first_column; i<= last_column; i++)
    if(i%2==1) sheet.hideColumns(i);
}
```

Where `first_column` is number of column, which you want to hide first, and `last_column` — number of last.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a script like this with onOpen trigger

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.hideColumns(1);  
  sheet.hideColumns(3);     
  sheet.hideColumns(5);     
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @player0, it's working. Can I assign this script to button and it will be so helpful if there is unhide function work with this like if I click the button, it will hide and clicking on the same button unhide it again?

Comment: @BaburRashid sure, you can bind it to the button

Comment: Can I bind two functions in one, so it will work for both, hide and unhide?? @player0

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Apps Script to hide multiple column using the [`hideColumn`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumncolumn) method.

```
function hideColumns() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("{MY SPREADSHEET'S ID}").getSheetByName(
    "{MY SHEET'S NAME}");
  sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange("J:S"));
}
```

We hope that this is useful for you. Please, don't hesitate to offer us more information for further help